# How to multiply values inside a nested list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a nested list:

list = [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]

I would like to multiply all items inside each nested list by each other to create a new nested list as follows:

[[2], [6], [24]]

I can do this for a single list but not sure how to for a nested list. Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: Not certain why this was closed.  It seems pretty focused and succinct to me.  And it only focuses on one problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

lst = [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
lst=list(map(np.prod, lst))
```

Outputs:

```py
[2, 6, 24]
```

Comment: Does not appear to be part of python-3.x

Comment: I'm sorry- which part? This will work on python 3x

Comment: I'm new at Python. But I am using Python 3.8 and it says it can't find the module when I do the import statement.  I am doing it under Cygwin.

Comment: ```pip import numpy``` will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

another way is:

```
from functools import reduce
List = [[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]
resultList = [[reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,List[i])] for i in range(len(List))]
```

result:

```
[[2], [6], [24]]
```

I am not sure you can understand this idea.
An easy way to do this is(not pythonic):

```
lst = [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
resultList = []
for i in lst:
    SUM = 1
    for j in i:
        SUM *= j
    resultList.append([SUM])

print(resultList)
```

Comment: Appreciated, thank you.